# Modular Arithmetic negative numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Hi I am having difficulty seeing why $-5 \bmod 3 \equiv 1$.

I know this:

$A/B = Q$ remainder $R$ and that is equivalent to

$A \bmod B \equiv R$

So when I divide $-5/3$ I’m not getting remainder 1.

Comment: $-5=2\times(-3)+1$

Comment: I think you will benefit from a new perspective on mods: $a\equiv b\bmod n$ iff $n$ is a divisor of $a-b$.

Comment: Please visit [this page for a MathJax and $\LaTeX$ tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so that you can write math effectively on this site.  There is no reason to use a greek letter Xi, $\Xi$, rather than $\equiv$ to denote equivalence.

Comment: As for another way of seeing the result... recognize that the equivalence class of $1$ modulo $3$ is equal to the set $\{\dots,-8,-5,-2,1,4,7,10,\dots\}$ and is the set of all integers who are one more than a multiple of three... they are evenly spaced three apart from one another, and this extends indefinitely not only in the positive direction but *also* in the negative direction.

Comment: As for "So when I divide $-5/3$ I'm not getting remainder $1$... let's look at this statement more closely.  So, you divide $-5/3$... you get what?  $-(1.\overline{6})$?  And so then we floor that.  Recall... flooring does not take us *towards zero* on the number line wherever we may be.  It takes us to the *left* on the number line wherever we may be.  So, the floor of $-1.\overline{6}$ is $-2$, not $-1$.  Continuing as such, we get that $-5/3 = (-2) + \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: -5 = -2 x 3 + R, then you can find R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Euclidean division in $\mathbf Z$, the quotient is the greatest integer $q\in \mathbf Z$ such that $qb\le a$ and the remainder satisfies  $0\le r <|b|$.

Therefore, in the present case, $q=-2$ and $r=a-qb=-5+2\cdot 3=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that modulo $3,$ any multiple of $3$ is effectively $0,$ so that we have that $$-5=-5+0=-5+3=-2+0=-2+3=1\pmod 3.$$